# Persist spring-retry retries during restart

Tags: spring-retry

Is there a mechanism in spring-retry that persist retries during restarts?

I would need that for a spring-boot application deployed in tomcat.

Edit:
As an alternative I would see a queue or quartz-scheduler as solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you would have to implement a custom `RetryContextCache` that persists the retry state to some backing store. You would then inject your custom cache into the `RetryTemplate`.

Comment: Did you implement it? Works?